# Purpose of wrapping with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, anonymous-function

I'm building a chrome extension and included the following code in my content script. [pep](http://pep.briangonzalez.org/) is a library for making things draggable. Interestingly, my code worked for case #2 but not #1. Why is that so?

It seems like the second case is wrapping the function call with an anonymous function (although I'm not sure why the jquery is needed before that)

```
//1
$('#square').pep();

//2
$(function($) {
    $('#square').pep();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second case is jQuery's shorthand for "on document ready".

It's the equivalent of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#square').pep();
});
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you are using a shorthand for `$(document).ready()`. That way the javascript waits for all the DOM elements to load before executing. The library needs all element to be loaded in order to work.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

A function passed to [jQuery constructor](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), `$(function() {})`, is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {});`

The function argument doesn't have to be anonymous, in fact, it's a good practice to always name such functions like so `$(function myDomReady() {})`.